# Should I use getTransactionCount() result in sendTransaction()?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, nonce, sendtransaction

As I read, `getTransactionCount()` returns the number of transactions sent from an address. Which of below items should I consider?

1. Not to use returned nonce?
2. Use the returned nonce number as a parameter in `sendTransaction()` to avoid duplicate transactions?
3. Use the returned nonce number + 1 to avoid duplicate transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the problem of double-spending, each transaction is sent with a nonce.

What is a nonce?

A nonce is an integer value that represents the number of transactions that have been performed from an account (ethereum adddress).

Which of the below items should I consider?

1. Not to use returned nonce?

*You should not use this, as some transaction with this nonce has already been submitted to the network.*

2. Use the returned nonce number as a parameter in sendTransaction() to avoid duplicate transactions?

*No, the reason is same as that of point 1*

3. Use the returned nonce number + 1 to avoid duplicate transactions?

*Yes*

Comment: This is wrong! Nonce start at zero. You have to use the value that getTransactionCount returns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the returned nonce number + 1 to avoid duplicate transactions

Comment: Provide a bit of explanation about the answer, always.

Comment: This is wrong! Nonce start at zero. You have to use the value that getTransactionCount returns.